# php error log does not include deprecated messages

Tags: php, apache2, error-reporting

I have a development server running ubuntu 16.04, apache2, PHP and MySQL.  The production server hosted offsite has requested that I upgrade the PHP version above 7.0 which I tried and discovered that I'm getting numerous PHP Deprecated: messages.  On my development server, I also upgrade the PHP version to 7.3 (and I have also tried 7.4) but these messages are not being displayed.

My web applications makes the following call as the first thing on each page request:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

I have confirmed that the php.ini contains the line:

```
display_errors = On
```

The errors being displayed on the production are real and I would like to get them fixed and tested in the development environment prior to pushing the changes into production.

Is there something else that I need to set to get these PHP Deprecated error messages displayed?  It appears that some of these are fatal errors in PHP 7.4.

Comment: First thing to check: your development server is actually running the version you think it is. Try running `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have done this as well and I'm running version 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Messages could be filtered out by PHP and by Apache:

- PHP: [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) should include `E_DEPRECATED`.
- Apache: [`LogLevel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) should be at least `info`.

In your case, the Apache configuration is probably missing.